# How can I use StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase

Tags: c#, list, string-comparison

I would kike to ask where in my code I can put the StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase?

```
Console.Write("Enter First Name: ");
var firstName = Console.ReadLine();
item = entries.PhonebookList.Find(y => y.FirstName == firstName);
isFirstNameExist = entries.PhonebookList.Contains(item);
```

Since on my list all the first letter starts with the capital letter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to compare values using `Equals` override that takes `StringComparison`:

```
...
var firstName = Console.ReadLine();
item = entries.PhonebookList.Find(y => y.FirstName.Equals(firstName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
...
```

Remember that `Find` returns `default` value if the all elements does not match the conditions